# Rectify the error caused due to non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE (description, price) IN (SELECT description, price FROM product
                               WHERE name = 'Colgate Active Salt');
```

Hi all just trying to work with multiple column sub query which pops up with the above error,the same code seems to work perfect with the oracle but not with the MS SQL.

Solutions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support this tuple syntax (which is however supported on other databases such as MySQL).  As a workaround, you may use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p1
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM product p2 WHERE p2.description = p1.description AND
                                    p2.price = p1.price AND
                                    p2.name = 'Colgate Active Salt');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your query as it involves only one table.

```
Select a.name, a.description from product 
where name = 'Colgate Active Salt'
```

As your question you should use the IN as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Another way is to use `inner join` to retrieve records which have have the same `description` and `price` as of `Colgate Active Salt`.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM product
    WHERE name = 'Colgate Active Salt'
    ) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM product
    ) b ON a.description = b.description
    AND a.price = b.price
    -- AND a.name = b.name
```

Comment: I'm just trying to retrieve records which have have the same description and price of 'Colgate Active Salt'

Comment: @Irfan In your question you have not given what you want rather than only technical error.

Comment: Requesting to retract the down vote as per the updated answer. Thanks.